# C# Ninject IIS express - continually loading/unloading

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, ninject, iis-express

We have .net4 web app running - pretty standard monolith architecture, Api to service to repository via interfaces using Ninject for Dependancy Injection.

It is now running superslow and it looks like it has something to do with ninject and iisexpress.
In the output we're seeing dozens of these sorts loading/unloading messages on every request.

```
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: NinjectModuleLoader): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Net.Http\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Net.Http.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: NinjectModuleLoader): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\api\bf4244e9\9647815a\assembly\dl3\3233e274\006a99c0_4448d001\Ninject.Web.WebApi.WebHost.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Domain 3): Unloaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: NinjectModuleLoader): Unloaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\System.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: NinjectModuleLoader): Unloaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll'
```

We have tried updating our version of ninject to make sure that wasn't the cause.
We have also tried shifting between IIS Express and local IIS.

Has anyone experienced a similar issue that might be able to shed some light on this?

Comment: https://www.tessferrandez.com/blog/2008/11/06/troubleshooting-appdomain-restarts-and-other-issues-with-ETW-tracing.html Use ETW to learn why app domains are reloading and that can guide you through to the culprit.

Comment: There was a similar discussion here that may provide some help for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29304720/iis-express-loads-and-unloads-modules-for-each-request Not sure if it will help.